# How to dynamically select given columns from a SAP CDC linked service?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sap-erp, sap-bw, sap-crm

In Azure Data Factory, I have a dynamic pipeline that extracts data from our SAP systems. The metadata for each given table (which are around 2000) is extracted via a lookup from which I get the name, ODP context, key columns and connection related details, like so:
[image: Metadata output]

Afterwards, I have a data flow that extracts the data and sinks it to a .parquet file:
[image: Pipeline]
[image: DF - Source settings] [image: DF - Source settings] [image: Sink Settings] [image: Sink mapping]

I can figure out how to assign most of the parameters dynamically, but I struggle to figure out how to make a selection only of the columns given in my metadata (KeyColumns) and not the entire object. I am running only full loads.

I have tried to run it as Full load then incremental, where I parsed the key columns to the Key Columns parameter, but not surprising, the whole object was loaded since this parameter indicates columns used for de-duplication.

Answer (score 0):

To make a selection only of the columns given in the metadata and not the entire object, you need to use select transformation. Giving the expression in `Key columns`, does not help you in selecting the desired columns dynamically. `Key columns` are used for incremental data loading. Below is the way to do using `select transformation`.

- Take the **select transformation** after source transformation.

[image]

- Click **+Add mapping** and select **Rule based mapping**
- Give the expression in source column of mapping as `in($<array_parameter_name>,name)`.

Here replace <array_parameter_name> with parameter name which contains the array of column names.  `name` is the keyword which is used here to check if any of the column names matches with value in the array.